# How to change the whole Action Bar menu to appropriate fragment in navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Can anyone tell me how to change the whole Action Bar menu to appropriate fragment in navigation drawer?

My code:

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater menuInflater)
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,menuInflater);
        menu.clear();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_history,menu);
    }
```

Comment: Use `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in your fragment.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

in onCreateView of your fragment.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please mark that as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

this method should be placed in onCreateView override method in fragment and

```
this.invalidateOptionsMenu()
```

this method shoulde be placed NavigationDrawerActivity when you create the fragment object.